# Check if SAP Login Successfully

Tags: vba, sap-gui

Through my VBA code I logon to SAP. I am trying to check if the login was successful using the following line of code: `session.findbyId("wnd[0]/sbar").MessageType = "S"` but it keeps printing false although I did successfully login. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if `session.Info.user` contains the user name you used to logon with. In that case you are logged on.

Or you check if `session.Info.user="SAPSYS"`  or `session.Info.user=""`. In that case you still have the Logon Screen and you are not logged in.